# RegEx SQL, issue escaping quotes

Tags: regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use PSQL, specifically AWS Redshift to parse a line. Sample data follows

```
{"c.1.mcc":"250","appId":"sx-calllog","b.level":59,"c.1.mnc":"01"}
{"appId":"sx-voice-call","b.level":76,"foreground":9}
```

I am trying the following regex in order to to extract the appId field, but my query is returning empty fields.

```
'appId\":\"[\w*]\",'
```

Query

```
SELECT app_params,
   regexp_substr(app_params, 'appId\":\"[\w*]\",')
FROM sample;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

`(\"appId\":\"[^"]*\")(?:,)`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xP0hW3

The first extracted group is what you want.
Your regex was not matching because `\w` does **not** match `-`

Comment: I don't think I can pick an extract group using redshift. But I now have "appId":"blah" returning so its a great improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this here despite this being an old question since it may help someone viewing this down the road...

If your lines of data are *valid* json, you can use Redshift's [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) function to extract the value a given key. Emphasis on the json being valid, as it will fail if even one line cannot be parsed and Redshift will throw a JSON parsing error.

Example using given data:

```
select json_extract_path_text('{"c.1.mcc":"250","appId":"sx-calllog","b.level":59,"c.1.mnc":"01"}','appId');
```

returns `sx-calllog`

This is especially useful since Redshift does not support lookahead/lookbehind (it is POSIX regex) & extract groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using some lookahead and look behinds to isolate just the text inside the quotes for the appid.  `(?<=appId\":\")(?=.*\",)[^\"]*`.  I tested this out a bit using your examples you provided [here](http://rubular.com/r/u2DWWaqCwX).

To explain the regex a bit more: `(?<=appId\":\")(?=.*\",)[^\"]*`

1. `(?<=appId\":\")`: positive look behind for `appid":"`.  Since you don't want the appid text itself being returned (just the value), you can preface the regex with a look behind to say "find me the following regex, but only when it is following the look behind text.
2. `(?=.*\",)`: positive look ahead for the ending `",`.  You don't want quotes to be returned in your match, but as with number 1 you want your regex to be bounded a bit and a look ahead does that.
3. `[^\"]*`: The actual matching portion.  You want to find the string of chars that are NOT `"`.  This will match the entire value and stop matching right before the closing `"`.

EDIT: Changed the 3rd step a little bit, removed the `,` from that last piece, it is not needed and would break the match if the value were to actually contain a `,`.